# Log SQL Server Password change

Tags: sql-server, security, windows-xp, passwords, password-protection

I have a recent unfortunate event. I host a business partner's SQLServer 2005 server, and the "sa" password was mysteriously changed (nobody wants to take responsibility on it). So I was wondering, **is there a way I can configure SQL Server 2005 to log all password changes?**

I know that could be achieved with Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008 or similar. But the thing is, I am running on Windows XP Pro (I know I should not be doing this, but my business partner claims she doesn't have the budget to buy a full fledge Windows Server OS).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas...

1. Using SQL profiler, [Audit Login Change Password Event Class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190672(SQL.90).aspx)
2. [DDL triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(SQL.90).aspx), specifying [ALTER USER DDL event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189871(SQL.90).aspx)
3. Rename "sa", create a dummy "sa" account

Anyone with rights to change sa passord will be able to undo or switch off any auditing though

Answer (score 0):

Do they have enough money to recreate the database from scratch once you loose data for the second time? Seriously, you should simply the Windows event viewer to see the last access. SA typically will show an event in the the security log.

Answer (score 0):

gbn had the correct ideas

Researching the same topic I found an excellent example written by Aaron Bertrand.
Essentially you need to create an event with the AUDIT_LOGIN_CHANGE_PASSWORD_EVENT parameter

```
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION PasswordChangeNotification
    ON SERVER WITH FAN_IN
    FOR AUDIT_LOGIN_CHANGE_PASSWORD_EVENT
    TO SERVICE 'PasswordChangeService', 'current database';
GO
```

you can find his example here
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2708/tracking-login-password-changes-in-sql-server/

Comment: Answering in links is discouraged in Stack overflow. Provide the portion of that page that answers the question of OP in your answer so that future readers may be able to read it even if the link is broken.

Comment: it would require a large chunk from that website to give a complete answer... and that would feel like stealing for me... anyway you can find a backup on archive.org, that way I don't  think it will go missing ever...

Comment: As a standard practice, you could include essential parts from the original thread. Now in this case, you could include idea to implement the solution exactly and include link at bottom for the further reference.